How to disable DateTimePicker Options Based on Multiple time interval Selection?
I have a workHours Object where each day can have multiple work time like this
  monday: {
    active: true,
    hours: [
      { from: '09:00', to: '12:00' },
      { from: '17:00', to: '23:30' }
    ]
  },...

I want the time picker to disable the time outside the interval not just allow all time from 9 to 23 and disable the rest but to disable also from 12 to 17
  <DateTimePicker
 value={localDeliveryTime}
 mode="datetime"
 textColor="red"
 display="default"
 onChange={onChange}
 minimumDate={minDate}
maximumDate={maxDate}
/>

